# What is the name of the theorem of tridiagonal reduction of symmetric matrices?

Tags: diagonalization, symmetric-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

I have over the last year been implementing a code to solve the many-body Schrödinger equation for applications in Nuclear physics, as part of my PhD-studies. The most important step in that code is the use of the Lanczos algorithm to find the lowest eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian matrix. Like most numerical algorithms for diagonalization of symmetric matrices Lanczos reduces the matrix to a tri-diagonal matrix with the same eigenvalues which then can be diagonalized easily. In a summer course I took back in 2017 a lecturer cited a specific theorem that states that any symmetric (diagonalizable) matrix can be reduced to a tri-diagonal matrix. Unfortunately I did not write that down. Now that I'm writing my dissertation I would like to cite that theorem when I explain the Lanczos algorithm. I have been looking for it in every source I can think of but can't find any mentioning of such a theorem. Every text on numerical symmetric matrix diagonalization seem to take that property of symmetric matrices as obvious and don't cite any theorem. I wonder if anyone here knows the name of that theorem, or a source where it is shown?

Answer (score 1):

No theorem needs to be invoked in order to perform the similarity transformation in the Lanczos algorithm.  It is correct by construction.

In the comments, you cited [this link](https://slepc.upv.es/documentation/reports/str5.pdf) as a reference.  In section 2.1, $α_i$, $β_i$, and $v_i$ are *defined* by Eq. (1). $T$ is *defined* as the tridiagonal matrix using $α_i$ and $β_i$. $V$ is *defined* using $v_i$. When you have defined $T$ and $V$ in this way, if you re-write Eq. (1) as a matrix equation using these matrices, you get Eq. (3). And Eq. (3) is an orthogonal similarity transform.

This is why the algorithm is so brilliant.  If you pick the construction correctly, you automatically get a similarity transformation.

If you still have questions about the algorithm, then the misunderstanding involves one of the steps above, probably the step where you re-write Eq. (1) as a matrix equation.

---

As an aside, I want to point out that there are important things left to be proved; it's just that they come after Eq. (3). There are at least three things that pop out at me:

1. Typically we halt the iteration before getting to $n$ and argue that $T$'s extreme eigenvalues and eigenvectors are similar to $A$'s. This needs proof, and I have never read a full proof of this, but I have heard that it is easy for Hermitian matrices and hard for non-Hermitian matrices (Arnoldi iteration).
2. How do we know that none of the $v_i$ are zero vectors?  (If any of them were zero, then $V$ would not be an orthogonal matrix.  We do, however, know that they are all orthogonal by construction.)
3. How do we know that the algorithm will be numerically stable in practice? (The naive approach isn’t.)

Comment: Thanks, but that do not answer my question. We use the Lanczos algorithm because we are studying Quantum-mechanical problems where only the lowest eigenvalues (extreme eigenvalues) are of interest and doing full diagonalization is not practical since the dimension of basis can easily be in the order of ten billion or higher.

Comment: Sure, I have worked on the exact same class of problems myself. Are you asking why the Lanczos algorithm produces a tridiagonal reduced matrix?  It does so *by construction*. Wikipedia almost certainly has the derivation, but I can elaborate later if there is something you don’t understand there.

Comment: When using the Lanczos algorithm, it’s important to note that you are not really “reducing” the matrix to tridiagonal form. (This is why I brought up the QR algorithm.). With Lanczos, you are actually constructing a *new*, smaller tridiagonal matrix from the original one. It just happens that the new matrix has approximately the same extreme eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors as the original matrix.

Comment: No, I'm not asking why Lanczos produces a tri-diagonal matrix. I'm asking for the name of the theorem that states that any symmetric matrix can be reduced to tri-diagonal form since it is used in the derivation of Lanczos, and other diagonalization algorithms. Yes, it is true that as long as you don't iterate Lanczos fully you get a smaller tri-diagonal matrix with approximations of the eigenvalues.

Comment: 1. I’m working from memory, but I really cannot think of any reason why the Lanczos method relies on this fact. Can you provide a reference where they invoke this? 2. QR decomposition *does* depend on this. I can’t remember ever learning the name of a theorem here, but the basic name for this is [Householder reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation). If you read the references in the “tridiagonalization” section in that link there may be a reference to a specific theorem. But from the method it is clear that, for a Hermitian matrix, then you can get a tridiagonal one.

Comment: If this ends up resolving your question, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: @user1690991 Did you ever figure out an answer to your question?

Comment: I have not figured out an answer to my question

Comment: If you can't find a reference that invokes this theorem, then I think it is a misunderstanding.  The Lanczos method does not require it.  But the theorem you are looking for is so widely known that simple sources do not cite it.  ...

Comment: ... The Wikipedia page on the QR algorithm cites [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm#cite_note-Demmel-5) and the following reference when it says that the first stage is to make the matrix Hessenberg by applying Household transformations.  (Note that a symmetric Hessenberg is tridiagonal.)  Finally, of course, all of this discussion is a much weaker result than the [spectral theorem for Hermitian matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem), which shows that you can actually make the matrix diagonal.  (All diagonal matrices are also tridiagonal.)

Comment: In this source [link](https://slepc.upv.es/documentation/reports/str5.pdf) under section 2.1, they out line the approach to deriving Lanczos that I have been following where the initial goal is stated as reducing the symmetric matrix to tri-diagonal form. My problem is that it is not motivated that it is always possible to do such an reduction.

Comment: This is what I have been saying all asking. You are confused because no theorem was ever invoked, nor does one need to be. $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ and $v_i$ are *defined* by Eq. (1). $T$ is *defined* as the tridiagonal matrix using  $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$. $V$ is *defined* using $v_i$. Then, when you have defined $T$ and $V$ in this way, if you re-write Eq. (1) as a matrix equation using these matrices, you get Eq. (3). And Eq. (3) is an orthogonal similarity transform. This is why the algorithm is so brilliant.

Comment: This isn’t to say that there is nothing left to be proved. There are at least three things that pop out at me. 1. Typically we halt the iteration before getting to $n$ and argue that $T$’s extreme eigenvalues and eigenvectors are similar to $A$’s. Why?  2. How do we know that none of the $v_i$ are zero vectors?  3. How do we know that the algorithm will be numerically stable in practice?  (The naive approach isn’t.)

Comment: But my point is: There is no magic in deriving Eq. (3). It is just definitions along with $A$ being symmetric/Hermitian.

Comment: @user1690991 If this addresses your question, I’ll put it in the answer.